# What is the most efficient way of uploading files in React Native?

Tags: react-native, file-upload, multipartform-data, react-native-fs

I'm working on a React Native App which will heavily rely on uploaded images and videos of users. Users will be able to upload a profile picture but can also later on upload short videos (under 1 min) similar to Instagram or Snapchat Stories. I'm now thinking about what the most efficient way of uploading theses files would be.

Right now I'm sending profile pictures through `form-data` to my backend, this works fine because the images are quite small (avg. around 80kb). But When I later want to send videos which can have a length of 1 minute I don't think that `form-data` would be the most efficient way, because I don't think that `form-data` chunks files.

I also want to be able to upload files while the app is in background. I found a few packages that ([react-native-background-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-upload), [react-native-compressor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compressor)) seem to be able to achieve that.
But I think they are also using `form-data` to upload the file. Is `form-data` the most efficient way of uploading files or is there an alternative that is more efficient?

[React-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#file-upload-android-and-ios-only) also seems to have an upload function but I don't know if their implementation is faster than the others.

Comment: Hi Jonas I am trying to achieve something similar could you share what approach did you take and which libraries did you use